# How to avoid particles glitching together in an elastic particle collision simulator?

Tags: javascript, simulation, collision

Here is a [short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wN8u-ERVaww) in which can be seen that groups of two (maybe more) particles are glitched into each other.

The source-code can be found [here](https://github.com/fibonatic/particleSim).

And this is the code I use to calculate the collisions with:

```
function collisionPhysics()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < N; ++j)
        {
            var Dx = objects[j].x - objects[i].x;    // Difference in X direction between objects[i] and objects[j].
            var Dy = objects[j].y - objects[i].y;    // Difference in Y direction between objects[i] and objects[j].
            var D2 = Dx * Dx + Dy * Dy;              // Distance between objects[i] and objects[j] squared.

            if (D2 <= (objects[i].rad + objects[j].rad) * (objects[i].rad + objects[j].rad))    // Colision check could be inserted here, reusing D2.
            {
                var delta = 2 * (Dx * (objects[i].Vx - objects[j].Vx) + Dy * (objects[i].Vy - objects[j].Vy)) / (D2 * (objects[i].m + objects[j].m));
                objects[i].Vx += -objects[i].m * delta * Dx;
                objects[i].Vy += -objects[i].m * delta * Dy;
                objects[j].Vx +=  objects[j].m * delta * Dx;
                objects[j].Vy +=  objects[j].m * delta * Dy;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2013/04/06:**
The issue nwellcome mentioned was causing the strange behavior. And this adjusted function should solve this, not sure if it could be improve performance wise but it works:

```
function collisionPhysics()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < N; ++j)
        {
            var Dx = objects[j].x - objects[i].x + timeStep * (objects[j].u - objects[i].u);
            var Dy = objects[j].y - objects[i].y + timeStep * (objects[j].v - objects[i].v);
            var D2 = Dx * Dx + Dy * Dy;              // Distance between objects[i] and objects[j] squared.

            if (D2 <= (objects[i].r + objects[j].r) * (objects[i].r + objects[j].r))    // Colision check could be inserted here, reusing D2.
            {
                objects[i].col = true;
                objects[j].col = true;
                var dx = objects[j].x - objects[i].x;
                var dy = objects[j].y - objects[i].y;
                var du = objects[j].u - objects[i].u;
                var dv = objects[j].v - objects[i].v;
                var dr = objects[j].r + objects[i].r;
                var dt = (-Math.sqrt(2 * dx * du * dy * dv - du * du * (dy * dy - dr * dr) - dv * dv * (dx * dx - dr * dr)) - dx * du - dy * dv) / (du * du + dv * dv);
                Dx = objects[j].x - objects[i].x + dt * (objects[j].u - objects[i].u);
                Dy = objects[j].y - objects[i].y + dt * (objects[j].v - objects[i].v);
                D2 = Dx * Dx + Dy * Dy;
                var delta = 2 * (Dx * (objects[i].u - objects[j].u) + Dy * (objects[i].v - objects[j].v)) / (D2 * (objects[i].m + objects[j].m));
                objects[i].u += -objects[i].m * delta * Dx;
                objects[i].v += -objects[i].m * delta * Dy;
                objects[j].u +=  objects[j].m * delta * Dx;
                objects[j].v +=  objects[j].m * delta * Dy;
                objects[i].x += (timeStep - dt) * objects[i].u;
                objects[i].y += (timeStep - dt) * objects[i].v; 
                objects[j].x += (timeStep - dt) * objects[j].u;
                objects[j].y += (timeStep - dt) * objects[j].v;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your method of collision resolution doesn't ensure that the particles won't still intersect at the beginning of the next frame.

When you find a collision, you need to work backward to the point in time when collision between boundary of the particles happened and resolve the collision from there.  Refer to [this game development answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/5949/12715) to a similar question for a method of doing that.

Comment: This indeed is causing the problem and after doing a little math I got a working collider. It also seems to work fine when a particle collides with two particles at once. Thanks, this is actually a very logical approach, don't know why I didn't think of this earlier.