# Collision detection using the Pythagorean theorem is being unreliable?

Tags: c++, physics

Objects can often times pass through each other? Additionally when calculating momentum, occasionally the sprites will form blobs upon collision, moving together instead of bouncing off.

The code does work for most collisions, but it often fails. Any ideas?

xV = X Velocity. yV = Y Velocity. Every frame this velocity values are added to the X and Y positions of the quad.

```
bool Quad::IsTouching(Quad &q)
{
    float distance = 0;
    float combinedRadius = (size/2) + (q.GetSize()/2);

    distance = sqrt(pow(q.GetX() - GetX(), 2) + pow(q.GetY() - GetY(), 2));

    if(distance < combinedRadius)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void Quad::Collide(Quad &q)
{
    float mX, mY, mX2, mY2, mXTmp, mYTmp;

    mX = mass * xV;
    mY = mass * yV;
    mXTmp = mX;
    mYTmp = mY;

    mX2 = q.GetMass() * q.GetxV();
    mY2 = q.GetMass() * q.GetyV();

    mX = mX2;
    mY = mY2;

    mX2 = mXTmp;
    mY2 = mYTmp;

    xV = mX/mass;
    yV = mY/mass;

    q.SetxV(mX2/q.GetMass());
    q.SetyV(mY2/q.GetMass());
}
```

Comment: What type of collisions do you mean? Elastic or inelastic? If only inelastic, then such behavior would be possible. If elastic and inelastic, specify. Also, add terms with reference to the sprites' kinetic and potential energy to tell elastic from non-elastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837065/how-to-avoid-particles-glitching-together-in-an-elastic-particle-collision-simul) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wN8u-ERVaww) is a quick video I made to demonstrate the problem.

The method to solve this is to calculate the exact time of the collision, so the particles would move the remaining time of the iteration/time-step with the new velocity. To do this you would have to check whether the will be a collision before updating the position, so: `sqrt((x1 - x2 + dt * (vx1 - vx2))^2 + (y1 - y2 + dt * (vy1 - vy2))^2) <= distance`.

You might also be able to get away with a simpler solution, in which you move both object slightly so that they aren't colliding anymore. This would yield a creator inaccuracy but does needs less calculations:

```
dx = x1 - x2;
dy = y1 - y2;
d = sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2);
D = r1 + r2;
if(d < D)
{
    s = (d - D) / (2 * d);
    x1 = x1 + s * dx;
    x2 = x2 - s * dx;
    y1 = y1 + s * dy;
    y2 = y2 - s * dy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What type of collisions are you referring to? Elastic or inelastic? For an elastic collision, the code would fail, and you would have to create an additional property to prevent the two objects from sticking together on contact. You would also have to ensure, with a loop or if statement, that if one object is crossing the position of another object at the same time as the other object, that the two will separate with an angle proportional to the collision speed. Use the appropriate physics formulae.

Comment: I guess my code is currently using elastic collision. Objects will bounce of each other at the correct angle for 7 out of 10 collisions. However when it fails objects will cross inside of each other and vibrate crazily until they explode apart unrealistically. I think they are continually swapping momentum, but I am struggling to come up with a way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Is there any way to make a "solid" property, and make these balls part of a solid class that acts in a certain way, such as non-overlapping? This class would follow certain methods that define its behavior. Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess that's what I am trying to do. Any suggestions for making this solid. I have tried on collision subtracting the xV and yV variables from the objects position to undo the pushing it inside of the other object when colliding. This doesn't seem to work though. Objects are still passing through each other.

Answer (score 0):

As a deduced, potential, issue (there are no values to the velocities, sizes, etc. supplied so I can't say for sure), you are not accounting that the quads are *exactly* touching. That is, `distance == combinedRadius`. Therefore, when this is true the check fails then the objects continue moving on the next tick...right through each other.

Change your check to `distance <= combinedRadius`. In addition, you may simply be getting a tunneling effect because the objects are small enough and moving fast enough that on each tick they pass through each other. There are multiple ways to fix this some of which are: impose a maximum velocity and a minimum size; increase your frame rate for physics checks; use continuous collision checks versus discrete checks: [see wikipedia article on subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_collision_detection#A_posteriori_.28discrete.29_versus_a_priori_.28continuous.29)

Comment: Will give this a try, as well as reading the article on Wikipedia. Thanks.