# [Physics][2D][Collision] What to do after dettecting collision

Tags: 2d, physics, collision, geometry

In the last project (2D top-down game) I had quite simple collision detections and how to deal with it after detection. Everything could move only in 4 directions - up/down/left/right. C.D. worked like that:

1. Move object as normal.
2. If object collides with other object move it back depending on what
   direction it was going on (e.g. going up and hitting something would
   move you just below this object)

But now i'm working on a project, that everything can move in 360*, so i can't really say where to move this object after detecting collision. As most objects have circle-type c.d. for me (top-down shooter) so I could do something like that:

1. Move object as normal
2. If object collides with other object, check angle between these two
   objects, and set the one which bumped on the other on the edge of
   others circle using computed angle.

Pics of how it would work:
[image: Physics idea]

And i'm not sure if this is proper way to do such thing.
Other idea is:

1. Compute new position but not save it yet
2. Check if new position does not collide with anything
3. If not - save position
4. If so - do not move

Its easier to detect it, but there would be gaps I guess?
So any ideas how to deal with collision when facing rounded objects that can move in 360* directions?

//Edit:
Also - game will be top-down 2D zombie-like shooter.
I did code both of these solutions and noticed:
If there is situation, that im standing in place, and there are two zombies one after another. When first comes to me he stops. In Angle version second goes around him and tries to go closer to me. In other version he just stops.
Everything would be good in Angel version, but if there are many "zombies" they tend to jump sometimes when they circle around and even get one on another. :| Techincally i could get past it as they would not have to be constant minimum distance between two zombies in games but sometimes it looks bad and i wouldn't like to decrease number of zombies at once becouse of that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837065/how-to-avoid-particles-glitching-together-in-an-elastic-particle-collision-simul) not so long ago. At first I just checked in each iteration if two balls where colliding and if so calculated there new direction and speed. However this sometimes resulted in weird collisions since it could happen that two balls had moved into each other.

To prevent this/calculate it correctly, you have to calculate the exact time of the collision after you have detected one. I have added the code in which I calculate this at the bottom of the question I linked.